# Anyway to stop a Chrome extension from detecting other extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have to use a certain Chrome extension for work and it is able to detect other extensions that I have installed. I really need to use another extension but my work extension is able to detect it and won't let me work. It's just a ridiculous rule and I was wondering if there is anyway around it. Is there anyway to block extensions from detecting other extensions that I have installed?

Comment: You would have to make a local copy of the Yukon extension (that's it isn't it?), modify its code, and install that modified copy as unpacked extension.

Comment: This question does not show research effort. You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)